# Google sheets script writing, how do I prevent an auto update or recacluation of my timestamps in googel sheets?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I attached a copy of the spreadsheet I run in google. The concept is when someone begins picking an order, they will for instance type their name in I3 and their time will start. once complete they will type their name in J3 , each causing a time stamp below leading to a total duration time. later it will factor percentages.

The problem is the time stamps seem to randomly update without prompting to do so. it seems to be when it is printed or reopened. This will cause inaccuracies in the times and percentages. Any assistance would be greatly appreciated

It would appear that I should write a script to accommodate this need, but I haven't the slightest on how to do this. I was directed to this forum from a reply in google docs help forum

[enter link description here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ZCbiE0trd082MN_pa2lJQ9bMccjYuUWotCz8a__8Sh4/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: Welcome. This site workings are different from other sites. Please take the [tour] and checkout [ask] to learn about the basics. Then add more details about you searched/researched.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can choose on which cell you update or recalculate (Tell me if I'm wrong).

A non-optimized workaround (Maybe some expert have got better solution):

```
function onEdit(e){

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
  var i = 3;

  while(i <= sheet.getLastRow())
  {    
    var data = sheet.getRange(i, 9, 3, 2).getValues();

    if(data[1][0].length == 0)
    {
      if(data[0][0] != "")
      {
        var d = new Date();
        sheet.getRange(i+1, 9).setValue(d);
      }
    }
    if(data[1][1].length == 0)
    {
      if(data[0][1] != "")
      {
        var d = new Date()
        sheet.getRange(i+1, 10).setValue(d);
      }
    }
    i=i+3;
  }
}
```

The [onEdit(e)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/) function is a simple trigger implement in Google Spreadsheet. It will trigger each time a cell is edit.

On this code above, we iterate to check on each element if a name was added or not. If so, the code will set the date and time below the name just added. Since you set the value on one single moment, no auto update will modify those time.

for this workaround, you need to remove the formula you put on the cell where you want your timestamp (i.e I4 and J4). You can keep the cells which calculate the difference between time, they should work with no problem.

Answer (score 0):

Paste below script in the script editor and save it.

```
function onEdit(e) {
if (e.range.rowStart % 3 != 0 || [9, 10].indexOf(e.range.columnStart) == -1) return;
var o = e.range.offset(1, 0);
if (!o.getValue()) o.setValue(new Date())
}
```

Don't run the script by clicking the play button in the script editor. Instead to back to any of the tabs, clear all cells where you now have the =now() formula and enter a name. See if the timestamp appears.